# Como obtener valor de una variable en otra pagina

Tags: php, html

quiero obtener el valor de una variable en otra pagina alguna ayuda soy nuevo, aqui esta mi codigo

```
session_start();
include="conexion.php";


 $query=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM productos");

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>

 //aqui tengo un while que me saca los nombres de los productos y tambien su respectivo id

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
          <li><a href="recivir_productos.php?id=<?php echo$row["id_product"]?>"><?php echo$row["product_name"]?></a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
//lo que hacer es que cuando yo de click en la etiqueta a recivir el id de ese producto en la otra pagina
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo para recibir el valor del id del producto en tu archivo recibir_productos.php .  mira este ejemplo

```
//obtienes el valor del id que estas enviando con get 

$_GET["id_product"];
//incluso puedes guardar ese valor en una variable para mas facilidad y reutilisamiento ejem:

$id_producto=$_GET["id_product"];
```

luego puedes hacer lo que necesites con el valor de ese id por ejemplo hacer comparaciones con condiciones  etc..

Comment: gracias me  fue muy util amigo

Answer (score 0):

He creado dos URL en localhost para implementar tu caso.

http://localhost/stackoverflow/catchGetParam.php

*La url 1 contiene tu link a ref*

[image: La url 1 contiene tu link a ref]

---

Con el siguiente código:

```
¡Hardcoding Values! 
<?php
    $row["id_product"] = 233;
    $row["product_name"] = "Curso de PHP con Laravel.";

<li><a href="recibir_productos.php?id=<?php echo$row["id_product"]?>"><?php echo$row["product_name"]?></a></li>
```

Y la URL 2:

http://localhost/stackoverflow/recibir_productos.php

*muestra la variable id por GET*

[image: muestra la variable id por GET]

---

Recibiendo parametros

```
<?php
 echo '¡Hola chosen, se recibió por GET el id '. $_GET["id"] .'!';
```

No olvides que si en tu URL el parametro es `id=XXX`, entonces en el código PHP se debe cachar el valor `así ===> $_GET['id']`,

```
 ...?XXPARAM=xValue =  $_GET['XXPARAM'];
```

*Mi versión de php es 7.2.4*

Comment: Hola @LeviArista, pero mi comentario expone una respuesta al problema. no es para preguntar.

Answer (score 0):

yo probaria con **require** si falla produce el error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) y para el script, **include** solamente reproduce una alerta (E_WARNING) pero el script continua podria ser que no estes cargando el script (conexion.php) y no te des cuenta de ello.

otro detalle que veo es que podrias estar haciendo el llamado pero no conecta(error de configuracion), prueba poniendole un codigo de confirmacion a la conexion a la base de datos,asi sabras si conecto, podrias usar un codigo como este despues del script de conexion (conexion.php):

```
<?php
```

//conectar a la base de datos

$mysql_server = "localhost";

$mysql_usuario = "usuariodb";

$mysql_contra = "contrasena";

```
// Conectando, seleccionando la base de datos
```

$link = mysql_connect('mysql_server', 'mysql_usuario', 'mysql_contra')
    or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());

echo 'conexion exitosa a la base de datos';

?>

si puedes inclusive selecciona la tabla en la base para que no tengas problemas de conexion, espero te sirva, comentas!